# data exchange with 2 web server without static IP Public

Tags: javascript, php, database, meteor, web

I have 2 web app in separate location (I'm planning to use meteor.js) with database on each. I want to exchange data between those 2 database when the transaction occurred on each site. But the problem is , each location only have dynamic ip public and the internet provider block VPN connection.

I also have 1 domain that hosted in internet , and the web server only provide PHP. So , I think maybe I can use the PHP as intermediate between them. Maybe I can make the system to copy the data to hosted database first and after that copy again to another site DB.

Are this solution can work ? Or maybe there is another better solution for this ? 
Thx

Comment: Have you considered DNS? There are providers that can handle dynamic IPs. Equally, you might consider switching to a better hosting provider that supports static IPs and/or VPNs.

Comment: yes , I think your suggestion can solve the problem. But I prefer not to install something in meteor web server device (we must install something for DDNS , please correct me if I wrong) . I had forgot to tell you before that the two meteor.js site using the mobile internet so that is a bit difficult to request the static IP. And in the future , I planning that I can add another Meteor web servers to this system without so much additional process. Thx a lot